# A convenient way to track memory allocated in a data loader?

Tags: c++, memory-management

In C++, we have to allocate/deallocate memory manually. In my loader function, this becomes a knotty problem. It loads data from a bunch of files containing different formats of data. And loading one file means doing a lot allocation in different places. The failure of one loading cause a total failure, which means I have to rollback all the allocation & initializition before. But the current design, using a lot of singletons, globals etc. doesn't provides a convenient way to rollback. I need suggestions or code samples to follow. Please help.

---

I guess build my own allocator is a good solution. But it doesn't works for foreign libraries used in my project who use their own allocators.

---

Please, don't say using smart pointers. It really means making my project more complicated.

---

So, some code is provided here. My project is a small interpreter. The language it interprets is XML. A complete program consists of several XML files, describing different data the program is using.

```
    extern std::map<std::string, Sub *> g_subMap;

    // ...

    // load every `subroutines' defined in XML
    // so what should I do if one of them fails to load?
    XMLElement *pRootElem = doc.RootElement();
    for (XMLElement *pChild1 = pRootElem->FirstChildElement(); pChild1; pChild1 = pChild1->NextSiblingElement()) {
            if (stricmp(pChild1->Value(), "sub") == 0) {
                    const char *name = pChild1->Attribute("name");
                    Sub *pSub = new Sub();
                    bool success = pSub->Load(pChild1);
                    // ?
                    g_subMap[name] = pSub;
            }
    }
```

Comment: "we have to allocate//deallocate memory manually" No we don't. That's we have smart pointers and RAII techniques.

Comment: Agree. I forget to mention this. I just want to avoid this kind of solution because it makes big changes.@Rakete1111

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I diagree - it is still allocated manually. Smart pointers et al. are just wrappers around new/delete.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes, but then it is not manually, but automatic: you don't have to worry about forgetting it, because the resources are automatically freed.

Comment: @brk This is like saying "I just want to avoid drinking water because it requires me to buy a mug."

Comment: @NickyC When you introduce smart pointers, you place mugs everywhere else, though most of them don't need one.

Comment: @brk - Can you show some sample code to show what the "knotty problem" actually is.  Although your problem simply sounds exactly like what RAII and smart pointer *patterns* are for, perhaps your problem can be solved in other ways.

Comment: @brk Sounds like a symptom of a wrong programming model. Without MCVE, this question is virtually unanswerable and there is no common ground for any discussion.

Comment: By the way, smart pointers exist to make your code **less complicated**.  Stating that it makes it more complicated suggests you actually don't understand the usage, syntax, or pattern.  But we're happy to teach.

Comment: @Rakete1111 Smart pointer is at its root a facility to program the automatic part of the language to do the manual things for you, so... both of you sounds right to me.

Comment: @selbie OK, I'll try post some code samples here. But I have already taught myself. Though suggestions are still be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you shared, here's a simple update.

Use a temp map to handle the loading.  The destructor of `subs` will release the reference when it goes out of scope. If it hasn't been copied over to g_subMap, as in the success case, then the temporary loaded "Sub" objects are deleted for you.

```
map<string, shared_ptr<Sub>> subs;
bool success = true;

for (XMLElement *pChild1 = pRootElem->FirstChildElement(); pChild1; pChild1 = pChild1->NextSiblingElement())
{
    if (stricmp(pChild1->Value(), "sub") == 0)
    {
        string name = pChild1->Attribute("name");
        shared_ptr<Sub> spSub = shared_ptr<Sub>(new Sub());
        subs[name] = spSub;

        success = spSub->Load(pChild1);
        if (success == false)
        {
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (success)
{
    // migrate our temp map of "subs" into g_subMap, which has
    // also been converted to be a map of shared_ptr<Sub>
    for (auto itor = subs.begin(); itor != subs.end(); itor++)
    {
        g_subMap[itor->first] = itor->second; // shared_ptr reference count gets incremented on assignment
    }
}    

// when "subs" goes out of scope it will decrement the reference count on each item in the map.  If the item wasn't copied over g_subMap, it gets deleted.
```

Comment: so can I interpret this solution as, `store all data loaded in a temp place. copy them to proper places only if the total loading process is complete.'?

Comment: Just made a few last minute bug fixes.  You can apply this suggestion how you want. But there's a lot of value in not having to worry about calling "delete" or writing "rolling back" as a result of allowing the destructors of existing collection and smart pointer classes do all that work for you.

Comment: OK I'll try. So maybe I am a smart pointer hater as a result of not using them frequently enough in my previous projects.